# How to use uniqid in for loop?

Tags: php

I want to upload multiple photos but when I create an uniqid, the photos look the same uniqid. How can I get around this?

```php
for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){

            $_FILES['files']['name'] = $files['galeri']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['type'] = $files['galeri']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] = $files['galeri']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['error'] = $files['galeri']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['size'] = $files['galeri']['size'][$i];


            $config['upload_path'] = "uploads/urunler/galeri/";
            $config["allowed_types"] = "jpg|jpeg|png";
            $config['max_size'] = '5000'; 
            $config['file_name'] = uniqid().$_FILES['files']['name'];
            


            $this->load->library('upload', $config); 


            if($this->upload->do_upload('files')){

                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $filename = $uploadData['file_name'];

                $galeri_arr['filenames'][] = $filename;

            }
        }
```

Result:

```json
{
0: "5f6fd81e54f1bimg52.jpg",
1: "5f6fd81e54f1bimg521.jpg"
}
```

Comment: is there anyone who can help?

Comment: *I create an uniqid, the photos look the same uniqid*, they are *not the same* but possibly could be (did you read the big red box in the docs?), what are you asking? Use more entropy, then hash it https://3v4l.org/qHOja... its better to hash the actual file contents using [sha1_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file), but if you don't want to do that use [hrtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php), which will almost certainly be unique because the call to the function is slower then a nanosecond https://3v4l.org/ovIP0 which again hash if you want *different*

Answer (score 0):

For generate unique file name best way is use timestamp in file name with `uniqid()`.

```
$config['file_name'] = uniqid().time().$_FILES['files']['name'];
```